# "Out of memory" error when executing large SQL query string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ms-access

I want to import my MS Access data to a MySQL database. I am using `xampp`. I wrote PHP code that fetches the Access table and creates a query string. When I execute my program it is giving me following error:

> Out of memory (Needed 2465528 bytes)

My code is:

```
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('my','','');/* connected */
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
$sqlstr="";

$tablefields=array("Name","City","State");

$sqlstr="INSERT INTO `mytable`(";

$temp=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($tablefields)-1;$i++)
{

    $sqlstr.="`".$tablefields[$i]."`";
    if($temp==count($tablefields)-2)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        $sqlstr.=",";
        $temp++;
    }

}

$sqlstr.=") VALUES";

//echo $sqlstr;

//return;
$sqlstr.="(";
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{ 

    $temp=0;
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
    {
        $sqlstr.="'".$value."'";
        if($temp==count($row)-1)
        {
            $sqlstr.="),(";
        }else
        {
            $sqlstr.=",";
            $temp++;
        }
        //echo $sqlstr;
    }



}    
$sqlstr.=")";

     connection();





$res=mysql_query($sqlstr)or die (mysql_error());




function connection()
{
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$database="mydatabase";

$cnx=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
echo (mysql_error($cnx));

mysql_select_db($database, $cnx);
echo (mysql_error($cnx));

return $cnx;
}
?>
```

I did change `max_execution_time = 3600` and `memory_limit = -1` in `php.ini`
and in `my.ini`

```
    key_buffer = 200M
    sort_buffer_size = 200M
    read_buffer = 200M
    write_buffer = 200M
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: did you restart xampp after changes?

Comment: What are the contents of `mytable`? Are there any LOBs?

Comment: ya i restart the xampp.and mytable contain 80 columns and 100mb size.it contain nearly 2 lac of records.

Comment: Have you tried it with `$sql="SELECT TOP 10 * FROM mytable";` to verify that it actually works with a smaller batch?

Comment: @ Gord Thompson ya it is working for small data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an insert every couple of hundred records. Something like this:-

```
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('my','','');/* connected */
$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
$sqlstr="";

$tablefields=array("Name","City","State");

$sqlhead="INSERT INTO `mytable`(`".implode("`,`", $tablefields)."`) VALUES ";

connection();

$sqlitem = array();
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{ 
    $temp=0;
    if (count($sqlitem) > 255)
    {
        $res=mysql_query($sqlhead.implode(',', $sqlitem))or die (mysql_error());
        $sqlitem = array();
    }
    $sqlitem[] = "('".implode("','",$row)."')";
}    

if (count($sqlitem) > 0)
{
    $res=mysql_query($sqlhead."(".implode('),(', $sqlitem).")")or die (mysql_error());
}

function connection()
{
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $database="mydatabase";

    $cnx=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    echo (mysql_error($cnx));

    mysql_select_db($database, $cnx);
    echo (mysql_error($cnx));

    return $cnx;
}
?>
```

You could do this a bit more cleanly by shifting the inserts off into a class (rather than just using an array). Pass each row to insert the class, and if the current total is above X then perform the insert, and also perform the insert from the destructor in the class. Saves having to decide at the end of the loop if you need to do more inserts.

Note, mysql_* functions are deprecated and you probably should use mysqli_* functions instead.

Comment: thank you very much kickstart... i appreciate your response. its working as i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For any future readers in a similar situation, a *much* better approach would be to use a prepared statement to do the INSERT operations. The advantages include:

- You don't have to guess what the "right" size of a batch of inserts should be.
- The code is more maintainable and extensible.
- It won't blow up if a text field contains a single quote.
- It is not vulnerable to SQL Injection problems.
- It is able to handle Null values correctly.

```php
<?php
$tablefields=array("Name","City","State");

$myDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=myDb', 'root', 'whatever');
$myDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$mySt = $myDb->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE mytable");
$mySt->execute();

$params = array_fill(0, count($tablefields), '?');
$sqlstr = "INSERT INTO mytable (`" . implode("`,`", $tablefields) .
        "`) VALUES (" . implode(",", $params) . ")";
// i.e., INSERT INTO mytable (`Name`,`City`,`State`) VALUES (?,?,?)

$mySt = $myDb->prepare($sqlstr);

$accDb = new PDO('odbc:' .
        'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' .
        'Dbq=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;');
$accDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sqlstr = "SELECT [" . implode("],[", $tablefields) . "] FROM myTable";
// i.e., SELECT [Name],[City],[State] FROM myTable

$accSt = $accDb->prepare($sqlstr);
$accSt->execute();

$rowCount = 0;
while ($row = $accSt->fetch()) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tablefields); $i++) {
        $params[$i] = $row[$tablefields[$i]];
    }
    $mySt->execute($params);
    $rowCount++;
}
echo $rowCount . " row(s) copied.<br />";
```